# Placing different values for Sys.sleep in a loop , multiple time values

Tags: r

I have a code and i am using a loop inside it , now i want this loop to be stopped for a short time interval after it completes one query. But when this loop executes the next query i want it to be stopped for different time interval.
For eg
After 1st query - 10sec
After 2nd query - 15sec and so on..

Following is the loop

```
for (i in 1:nrow(uniquemail)) {
    k <- 2
    test3 <- subset(finaltest, finaltest$Email == uniquemail[i,1])
    for (j in 1:nrow(test3)) {

      uniquemail[i,k] <- test3[j,2]
      uniquemail[i,k+1] <- as.character(test3[j,3])
      uniquemail[i,k+2] <- as.numeric(test3[j,4])
      uniquemail[i,k+3] <- as.numeric(test3[j,5])

      k <- k+4

      print(paste(i,j,k)) 
    }
  }
```

Is there any way i could get this done . I used `Sys.sleep` but don't know how to use it for my motive above .

Comment: `Sys.sleep()` takes one argument `time =`.

Comment: Yeah i get it , any other way ?

Comment: Why we don't want to use Sys.sleep?

Comment: I have to use it for multiple time values  for a loop , can this be done with it ? As i stated above in the question .

Comment: `Sys.sleep(10+5*(j-2))` Sleep ten seconds + 5 seconds per additional query?

Comment: @Choubi +5 seconds per additional query !! What if i have to run like 20,000 queries . Its gonna take ages that way .

Comment: @pankaj I had just figured that's what you wanted, ie: 10 secs after first query, 15 sec after second...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to create a sleep-loop for each iteration, and start the timing for sleeping duration **before** your actions, and increase the sleep with 5 seconds per loop you can use this code:
See below:

```
for (j in 1:3) {
tm <- proc.time() #take timing before your action

#do your things here
#
#

tmdiff <-(5 * j) - (proc.time()[3] - tm[3]) #you want to wait 5 seconds the first time,
#10 sec the second time, 15 sec the third time etc..

if (tmdiff > 0) {
  #depending of how long your "thing" took,
  print(paste("sleep for", tmdiff, "seconds"))#you are taking the difference from the start to end of "actions" and sleeping for that time
  Sys.sleep(tmdiff)
  }
}
```

if you want to start the sleeping duration **after** your actions:

```
for (j in 1:3) {    
    #do your things here
    #
    #  
      tmsleep<-(5 * j) #you want to wait 5 seconds the first time,
                       #10 sec the second time, 15 sec the third time etc..
      print(paste("sleep for", tmsleep, "seconds"))
      Sys.sleep(tmsleep)
    }
  }
```

Since we don't have any further information about your problem (nor a reproducible code), I assume your running into problems with overloading some type of API and/or webscraping. If so, I would rather sample my sleep time from a selected range of values such as:

```
tmsleep<-sample(5:15,1)
Sys.sleep(tmsleep)
```

i.e. sleep for a value between 5 to 15 seconds. Also if you want to have a predictable sleep time you can use `set.seed(j)`, where `j` is the looping variable:

```
set.seed(j)
tmsleep<-sample(5:15,1)
Sys.sleep(tmsleep)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution , but what if i have to keep running those time intervals again and again as a loop until my queries doesn't end ?

Comment: Now when I read your question you wanted to sleep _after_ an action and not time it between each action (i.e. before), as I've written in my answer. I have updated it so it fits your answer. For next time, please give us reproducible data so we can easier come up to a solution, which ultimately will benefit yourself!

Comment: Thanks buddy , this is what i needed . Apologies for the unclear question .

Answer (score 1):

"if i have to keep running those time intervals again and again as a loop until my queries doesn't end ?"

Before the loop:
You could create a vector of the timings you want, you can either create it yourself:

```
timings <- c(5, 2, 10, 8, 7)
```

Or generate one randomly, setting the seed if you want the same timings from one run to another:

```
timings <- sample(5:10, 10)
```

Inside your loop, use `Sys.sleep` with one value of your timings vector one after another. By using modulo length of your vector, this will wrap around at the first value when the vector is done.

```
Sys.sleep(timings[(i-1) %% length(timings) + 1])
```

Example of the modulo:

```
for (i in 1:15){      
  print(timings[(i-1) %% length(timings) + 1])
}
```

Output:

```
[1] 5
[1] 2
[1] 10
[1] 8
[1] 7
[1] 5
[1] 2
[1] 10
[1] 8
[1] 7
[1] 5
[1] 2
[1] 10
[1] 8
[1] 7
```

Comment: Well this is handy as well . Thanks !

Comment: @pankaj Happy you found it useful. To whomever: is there a reason to the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

```
sample(1:10,1,replace=TRUE)
```

Use this if you want it to be a random time internal instead of progressively larger values. Just set the first parameter to an appropriate number interval for what you're doing.